# Symfony2 IBAN Validator returns false for valid UK IBAN

Tags: regex, validation, symfony, preg-match

The Validation code looks like this:

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
            return;
        }

        $teststring = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value);

        if (strlen($teststring) < 4) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('{{ value }}' => $value));
            return;
        }

        $teststring = substr($teststring, 4)
            . strval(ord($teststring{0}) - 55)
            . strval(ord($teststring{1}) - 55)
            . substr($teststring, 2, 2);

        $letterToInt = function ($letter) {
            return intval(ord(strtolower($letter[0])) - 87);
        };

        $teststring = preg_replace_callback('/[A-Za-z]/', $letterToInt, $teststring);

        $rest=0;
        $strlen = strlen($teststring);
        for ($pos = 0; $pos < $strlen; $pos += 7) {
            $part = strval($rest) . substr($teststring, $pos, 7);
            $rest = intval($part) % 97;
        }

        if ($rest != 1) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('{{ value }}' => $value));
            return;
        }
    }
```

For a valid UK IBAN this test fails.
A Valid IBAN code looks like this: **GB29 RBOS 6016 1331 9268 19**

The test codes looks like

```
 public function getValidIbans()
    {
        return array(
            array('CH93 0076 2011 6238 5295 7'), //Switzerland
            array('CH9300762011623852957'), // Switzerland without spaces

            //Country list
            //http://www.rbs.co.uk/corporate/international/g0/guide-to-international-business/regulatory-information/iban/iban-example.ashx
            // array('GB29 RBOS 6016 1331 9268 19'), //United Kingdom -- currently fails!

            array('AL47 2121 1009 0000 0002 3569 8741'), //Albania
            array('AD12 0001 2030 2003 5910 0100'), //Andorra
            array('AT61 1904 3002 3457 3201'), //Austria
            array('AZ21 NABZ 0000 0000 1370 1000 1944'), //Azerbaijan
            array('BH67 BMAG 0000 1299 1234 56'), //Bahrain
            array('BE62 5100 0754 7061'), //Belgium
            array('BA39 1290 0794 0102 8494'), //Bosnia and Herzegovina
            array('BG80 BNBG 9661 1020 3456 78'), //Bulgaria
            array('HR12 1001 0051 8630 0016 0'), //Croatia
            array('CY17 0020 0128 0000 0012 0052 7600'), //Cyprus
            array('CZ65 0800 0000 1920 0014 5399'), //Czech Republic
            array('DK50 0040 0440 1162 43'), //Denmark
            array('EE38 2200 2210 2014 5685'), //Estonia
            array('FO97 5432 0388 8999 44'), //Faroe Islands
            array('FI21 1234 5600 0007 85'), //Finland
            array('FR14 2004 1010 0505 0001 3M02 606'), //France
            array('GE29 NB00 0000 0101 9049 17'), //Georgia
            array('DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00'), //Germany
            array('GI75 NWBK 0000 0000 7099 453'), //Gibraltar
            array('GR16 0110 1250 0000 0001 2300 695'), //Greece
            array('GL56 0444 9876 5432 10'), //Greenland
            array('HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000'), //Hungary
            array('IS14 0159 2600 7654 5510 7303 39'), //Iceland
            array('IE29 AIBK 9311 5212 3456 78'), //Ireland
            array('IL62 0108 0000 0009 9999 999'), //Israel
            array('IT40 S054 2811 1010 0000 0123 456'), //Italy
            array('LV80 BANK 0000 4351 9500 1'), //Latvia
            array('LB62 0999 0000 0001 0019 0122 9114'), //Lebanon
            array('LI21 0881 0000 2324 013A A'), //Liechtenstein
            array('LT12 1000 0111 0100 1000'), //Lithuania
            array('LU28 0019 4006 4475 0000'), //Luxembourg
            array('MK072 5012 0000 0589 84'), //Macedonia
            array('MT84 MALT 0110 0001 2345 MTLC AST0 01S'), //Malta
            array('MU17 BOMM 0101 1010 3030 0200 000M UR'), //Mauritius
            array('MD24 AG00 0225 1000 1310 4168'), //Moldova
            array('MC93 2005 2222 1001 1223 3M44 555'), //Monaco
            array('ME25 5050 0001 2345 6789 51'), //Montenegro
            array('NL39 RABO 0300 0652 64'), //Netherlands
            array('NO93 8601 1117 947'), //Norway
            array('PK36 SCBL 0000 0011 2345 6702'), //Pakistan
            array('PL60 1020 1026 0000 0422 7020 1111'), //Poland
            array('PT50 0002 0123 1234 5678 9015 4'), //Portugal
            array('RO49 AAAA 1B31 0075 9384 0000'), //Romania
            array('SM86 U032 2509 8000 0000 0270 100'), //San Marino
            array('SA03 8000 0000 6080 1016 7519'), //Saudi Arabia
            array('RS35 2600 0560 1001 6113 79'), //Serbia
            array('SK31 1200 0000 1987 4263 7541'), //Slovak Republic
            array('SI56 1910 0000 0123 438'), //Slovenia
            array('ES80 2310 0001 1800 0001 2345'), //Spain
            array('SE35 5000 0000 0549 1000 0003'), //Sweden
            array('CH93 0076 2011 6238 5295 7'), //Switzerland
            array('TN59 1000 6035 1835 9847 8831'), //Tunisia
            array('TR33 0006 1005 1978 6457 8413 26'), //Turkey
            array('AE07 0331 2345 6789 0123 456'), //UAE
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the UK IBAN is valid? I tried a number of online validators, and neither of them seemed to accept it.

You could try them yourself:
[www.paymentscouncil.org.uk](http://www.paymentscouncil.org.uk/resources_and_publications/iban_checker/)

[www.natwest.com](http://www.natwest.com/apps/secure/tools/iban_new/Iban/IBAN_Checker.aspx?Theme=rbs)

Your validator accepts `GB29 NWBK 6016 1331 9268 19` (taken from [here](http://www.ecbs.org/iban/united-kingdom-uk-bank-account-number.html)) and `GB19 LOYD 3096 1700 7099 43` (from [here](http://www.paymentscouncil.org.uk/resources_and_publications/iban_checker/)).

I think the checksum number in your IBAN number is incorrect, if you change it from `29` to `86` as such: `GB86 RBOS 6016 1331 9268 19` it will be valid.

Comment: I've tested on those sites with a valid IBAN number I got from a client. I have succesfully wired money to those IBAN's but they still fail the validator? Not keen on publicly posting those client's IBAN numbers though...